# HTML+jQuery - other HTML attribute that replaces ID

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML problem.

**Description**

I'm building an 'authors' page, and each author has a tabbed system. In one tab I have the Bio and on the other I have Other Information.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="author-container"><img src="author-1.jpg" alt="">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#inner-tab1">Bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#inner-tab2">Other Info</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="inner-tab1">Bio copy</div>
  <div id="inner-tab2">Other Info copy</div>
</div>

<div class="author-container"><img src="author-2.jpg" alt="">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#inner-tab1">Bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#inner-tab2">Other Info</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="inner-tab1">Bio copy</div>
  <div id="inner-tab2">Other Info copy</div>
</div>

<div class="author-container"><img src="author-3.jpg" alt="">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#inner-tab1">Bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#inner-tab2">Other Info</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="inner-tab1">Bio copy</div>
  <div id="inner-tab2">Other Info copy</div>
</div>
```

Yes, you've detected the issue: duplicate IDs (***inner-tab1*** and ***inner-tab2***)

Although the tabs actually work fine and I could certainly leave these duplicate IDs as is, I know this is not the right way to do it.

**Question**

So my question is: Is there another HTML attribute that can replace the `id` tag but still have the tabs work?

**Additional Information**

To create the tabs I'm using the jQueryUI framework, and that framework uses `id` in the container a specific tab should display.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are those tabs dynamically added or hardcoded?

Comment: The correct term here is not *tag*, but *attribute*. `div`,`ul`,`li` - those are tags.

Comment: @egasimus, yes, corrected, I must be too tired now. Tnx.

Comment: @Dimitri, well, I'm building an HTML mockup for the off-shore developers. But I advise not to let the developers interfere on how these tabs are handled since they can't handle intricate processes (yes, I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is already implemented as is, the only solution would've been to use a simpler tab system that wasn't based on IDs.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to implement simpler tabs and I had to bite the bullet and leave the duplicate IDs on the markup. It does work, but is far from ideal.

Lesson learned.

These tabs would've been the correct ones to use: http://nuevvo.com/labs/simpletabs/

Thanks all for your input.

Comment: Using duplicate ids cannot be a solution. Use classes, id patterns or even put custom attributes on that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Use a class name, and give the `id`s to the `author-container`s. Then, you can select elements with `$("#joe .inner-tab-2")`.

Comment: I'd love to do something like this, but I'm using jQuery UI which handles all the functionality/scripting. The only piece of script I need to write is `$('.secondary-tabs-s2').tabs();` (this is the outside wrapper, I didn't put it in the above code since it wasn't necessary). 

How would I overwrite jQueryUI's tab scripting code? Thanks.